# c# Calling Server side method using JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Im trying to call a server method in my aspx.cs to delete all the files in a directory when a user closes the browser.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void fileDelete()
    {

        string[] uploadedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Lambo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\testPdfIn");
        foreach (string uploaded in uploadedFiles)
        {
            File.Delete(uploaded);
        }
    }
```

======================================================================

EDIT

I've tried the POST method but it still doesn't seem to work. I've changed the URL too.

Over at the client side im using this:

```
    $(function () {
        $(window).unload(function () {
            alert("Files have been deleted")
             jQuery.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: "http://localhost:19642/success.aspx/fileDelete", async: true });
        });
    });
```

However it doesnt seem to be working. Are the codes wrong in someway?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: How is it not working?  Is the AJAX code executed?  Does it reach the intended server-side code?  What is the response from the server?

Comment: Are you trying to delete files on the server or client?  If server, it should be working.  If client, you'll need to run client-side code to do this, (I'm not sure if this can work, due to security restrictions) not server-side.

Comment: There's no error. The alert box pops up, but the method doesn't fire.

Comment: "wrong in someway" - yes: don't hardcode path to files, ASP.Net code may not have permission to access files there (both Windows and CLR permissions), don't make remote calls in unload.

Comment: I **think** the default type of ajax call in jquery is `GET` whereas to invoke the WebMethod in success.aspx I **think** you need to `POST`. (Heavy emphasis on think because I cannot currently test this theory).

Comment: I've tried using server.mappath, but it says that i cant use it in a static method

Comment: In addition you can debug using the `error` and `success` arguments for your ajax call and see (a) which method is called, and (b) what the response is.

Comment: to add to @GarethD comment about GET, sometimes browser caching will prevent the call from reaching your Server..not the case for POST.

Comment: I'm quite new to this, how do you POST?

Comment: Okay, i've tried adding type: 'POST' and changed the url but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To investigate failures of AJAX calls use HTTP debugger (like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) ) to see what requests are made and what responses are received.

My guess is that your Url is wrong and request is made to wrong file. Consider making absolute (or at lest server relative) url.